# Transforming a dataframe to a list, groupby() not working

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with the following shape:

```
Index  Col1 Col2 Col3  
 1      A    B    C
 2      D    E    F
 3      G    H    I
```

I would like to receive a data frame with the following shape:

```
1 Col1 A
1 Col2 B
1 Col3 C
2 Col1 D
2 Col2 E
...
```

Already went through .groupby(), pivot(), iterators but no success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need,

```
df.melt()
```

O/P:

```
    variable    value
0   Col1    A
1   Col1    D
2   Col1    G
3   Col2    B
4   Col2    E
5   Col2    H
6   Col3    C
7   Col3    F
8   Col3    I
```